# When should tuples be used instead of objects and vice versa?

Tags: object, tuples, semantics, swift

i learned about tuples today, in a nutshell they allow you to store several values, an example of tupel is

```
let exampleTuple = (exampleString: "This",  exampleInt: 1)
```

And we can easily access any value of a tuple with a dot notation, for example:

```
exampleTuple.exampleString
```

To me this seems extremely similar to objects holding certain information, I might be missing something or not understanding tuples completely, therefore I'm asking for an explanation on when we should use tuples or objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [book on Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_426),

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures.

They define "temporary" through the scope of the data: if a piece of data never leaves the scope of a single method, or a group of methods of the same object, it can be considered temporary, even though it might very well persist through the lifetime of an application.

If your data structure is useful outside a temporary scope - for example, because it needs to be returned from a public method of your class, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.

Another important consideration is associating behavior with your data: if your object needs to have methods, use classes for them. Use tuples only for data devoid of behavior.

Comment: I was going to answer this question by something similar to "It's like a Tuple object (static) but the language defined it as a fundamental type?".
and then I thought that even an Integer is like an object with just a property, and then that an object is just an array of byte. Defining the object type just define how to interpret the bytes it refer to right?

Comment: @Mayerz It looks like tuples are a fundamental type in swift, complete with strong support from the compiler. They feel like `struct`s that you define through examples. As far as object types go, they could be defined statically or dynamically. In case of tuples, the definition appears to be statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are heavily used in Python and it seems to me they have mostly the same purpose in Swift. Think of it as a **quick way to deliver multiple values** from one point to another. An example that shows up in the Swift book and a pattern that is used in Python very often is returning an HTTP status code and a text body from a method:

```
func greeting() {
    return (200, "Hello World")
}

...

let (status, body) = greeting()
if 200 == status {
    println(body)
}
else if status >= 400 {
    println("Error \(status): \(body)")
}
```

Of course this is just one use case, but I think it gets the point across. A built-in example is the function `enumerate()`, which returns a tuple of `(index, value)`:

```
for (idx, val) in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]) {
    println("Index \(idx): \(val)")
}
```